# How can I use std::enable_shared_from_this in both super and subclass?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, multiple-inheritance, weak-ptr, enable-shared-from-this

I have two classes `A` and `B`, where `B` is a subclass of `A`. I need both classes to use `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

I tried this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
  public:
    void insertme(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& v) {
        std::cout << "A::insertme\n";
        v.push_back(shared_from_this());
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    }
};

class B : public A, public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
  public:
    void insertme(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>& v) {
        std::cout << "B::insertme\n";
        v.push_back(std::enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this());
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> va;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> vb;

    std::shared_ptr<A> pa = std::make_shared<A>();
    std::shared_ptr<B> pb = std::make_shared<B>();

    pa->insertme(va);
    pb->insertme(vb);
}
```

(In order to avoid that `shared_from_this()` be ambiguous, I had to fully qualify it in `B::insertme`.)

When I run the above program, I get this output:

```
A::insertme
OK
B::insertme
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So `A::insertme` works, but `B::insertme` does not.

I'm using GCC 9.1.0 under Linux.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to (and only can) inherit from shared_from_this in the base class:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
  public:
    void insertme(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& v) {
        std::cout << "A::insertme\n";
        v.push_back(shared_from_this());
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    void insertme(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>& v) {
        std::cout << "B::insertme\n";
        v.push_back(std::static_pointer_cast<B>(shared_from_this()));
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    }
};
```

This means you need the explicit `static_pointer_cast` to get a `shared_ptr<B>`, but you could wrap that into an override in `B` if you want:

```
std::shared_ptr<B> shared_from_this() { return std::static_pointer_cast<B>(A::shared_from_this()); }
```

Comment: Thank you. I've accepted your answer, but with the caveat that I cannot find `static_pointer_cast` as a member function of `std::shared_ptr`. It does, however, exist as a non-member function: `std::static_pointer_cast<B>(A::shared_from_this())`

Answer (score 1):

The automatic linkage to `enable_shared_from_this<X>` that gets set up when a `shared_ptr<T>` is created only works if the class type `T` inherits exactly one unambiguous public `enable_shared_from_this` base. But `B` inherits two different `enable_shared_from_this` bases.

Instead, you can have just the `enable_shared_from_this<A>`, and write a custom `B::shared_from_this()` which makes use of `A::shared_from_this()`:

```
class B : public A {
  public:
    // These hide the A::shared_from_this(), but they can still be
    // used by qualification if wanted.
    std::shared_ptr<B> shared_from_this()
    { return std::static_pointer_cast<B>(A::shared_from_this()); }
    std::shared_ptr<const B> shared_from_this() const
    { return std::static_pointer_cast<B>(A::shared_from_this()); }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: "_only works if the class type T inherits exactly one unambiguous public `enable_shared_from_this` base_" note that here all base classes are public and unambiguous

Comment: True. Just covering the "bases" more generally.